# display one Measure for all dimensions sequentially in CrossTab table

Tags: birt, crosstab

I'm new in using  BIRT Report designer, My customer need report to be displayed as listing Sum of remittances for each currency horizontally then listing counts of remittances for each currency horizontally as in attached sample

[image: Sample crosstab table]

any suggestions please?
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: please give example data of your actual table/datasource. This should be possible with BIRT

Answer (score 0):

Create a datacube based on your original dataset. Now create two groups. One on 'country' and one on 'Currency' (ie EURO, DOLLAR)

Next create the two measures. Count(...) and sum(amount)

Drop a crosstab on your report canvas.

Use the dataexplorer to drag and drop groups/measures. Put the country group on the left and the currency group on the top.
Now drag and drop the two measures. Just drop the second one 'under' the first one and BIRT will automatically create two columns next to each other.

This wil result in something slightly different then requested though:

It will look like

```
|          |  EURO               | Dollar             |
-------------------------------------------------------
| Country  |  sum      | count   |  sum     | count   |
```

I'm not sure if you can turn that around, but I think you have to try to be creative with the groups.